# Angular 5 GET request nonresponsive

Tags: javascript, angular, bootstrap-4

I've seen many similar problems regarding this problem on this site, but they tend to be either too specific (with Django, Python, Spring, etc) or too outdated.

I am using Angular 5 and Bootstrap, using Chrome to debug, and my GET request does not GET, or give me any errors, or do anything, really. With zero output, I am not sure what I'm doing wrong.

My .ts file code:

```
onNameKeyUp(event:any) {
  this.id = event.target.value; //sets input to the object's id
  this.found = false;
}

getProf() {
this.httpClient.get(`api_url/${this.id}`)
.subscribe(
  (data:any[]) => {
    if(data.length) {
      this.name = data[0].name;
      this.id = data[0].id;
      this.found = true;
      }
    }
  )
}
```

My component.html code:

```
  <input type="text" (keyup)="onNameKeyUp($event)">
  <button type="button" (click)="getProf()">Get Profile</button>

  <div *ngIf="found">
    <div>{{this.name}}'s id is {{this.id}}</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Is ``get(`api_url/${this.id}`)`` the actual code? Or in your actual code is 'api_url' replaced with the actual URL?

Comment: It's replaced with the actual url in my code

Comment: If you check the Developer tools (F12) network tab, can you see the request being made? Is the response what you'd expect?

Comment: Yes, it shows the correct url with the requested id in it correctly, and a status of 200 next to it.

Answer (score 2):

replace `this.name` with `name` and `this.id` with `id` in your HTML

Comment: I get the error "cannot find name 'name'" "cannot find name 'id'" if I do that

Comment: Remove `this` in your html, not typescript file.

Comment: My bad! I still don't get any output though.

Answer (score 0):

Add error => to see the error, and then from there debug. You should see in your network tab if 404, 500, 200 etc.

```
this.httpClient.get(`api_url/${this.id}`)
    .subscribe(
      (data:any[]) => {
        if(data.length) {
          this.name = data[0].name;
          this.id = data[0].id;
          this.found = true;
          }
        },
        error => {
          console.log('See Error: ', error);
         }

         )
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, data is an array and is a type of class or interface. I would define a profile of that type above your constructor like so,

```
profile: any;
constructor(...) {}
```

If you are getting a valid data:

```
  if(data.length) {
    this.name = data[0].name;
    this.id = data[0].id;
    this.found = true;
    console.log(data); // ---------> this should be an array (F12 developers tool).
     this.profile = data[0]; // should not give you an exception error.
  }
}
```

Then in you html code.

```
 <div *ngIf="found">
   <div>{{profile?.name}}'s id is {{profile?.id}}</div>
 </div>
```

? -* Don't forget to include this. If this does not work, let me know and I'd be happy to help. Happy coding..