# Angular 5 GET request populate form fields

Tags: javascript, html, angular, forms, bootstrap-4

How would I go about filling in form fields with the information from a GET request? If the user enters the ID of an object in the API, all fields (name, age, phone, etc) need to be populated with that object's respective information.

I am using Angular 5 and Bootstrap for this project. The API I am querying has objects in JSON format, and I am able to send a POST request to the server (in the form of a JSON object).

Currently, my GET request does not respond to anything. No outputs in console or application, and I'm not sure why ([Angular 5 GET request nonresponsive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51199235/angular-5-get-request-nonresponsive)). Any pointing in the right direction would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

First create a service to make the rest call, service should have @Injectable() and be provided in your module. You must also import FormsModule and ReactiveFormsModule.

```
@Injectable()
export class SomeService {
 constructor(private http: HttpClient){}

  getSomeDataDude() {
   return this.http.get('someUrlDude');
  }

}
```

Then in your component you subscribe to said service, in your case I guess on the ngOninit or maybe even a resolve guard to retrieve the data before the component loads so you can populate the fields.

Resolve: https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-resolve-guard-example

Then once you have the data, just update the formControls, control.setValue or in the init new FormControl(valueHere, Validators.required);

Answer (score 0):

That really depends on where you store the information. (Database)
Firebase has an package (npm) that can access its database but most others you would probably use the Http package from angular. see DOC's here: https://angular.io/api/http/Http